# How do I Run python code from github in snowpark?

Tags: python, github, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have some custom code in https://git..../function.py
I want to fetch this code from git and run it within a python worksheet in snowpark.

How do I set this up? I am new with Snowpark.

I find it very difficult to find useful or clear instructions on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python worksheets are intended for writing the code directly in the worksheet in the Snowflake UI and running Snowpark Python directly in the worksheet. As it stands now, there isn't an integration available between git and a Python worksheet. You would need to copy your code into the worksheet, or put your .py code into a stage and then import the Python code into your worksheet from the stage.

See for reference the docs on Python worksheets: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/python-worksheets#add-a-python-file-from-a-stage-to-a-worksheet

Alternatively, you could run your git code in Snowpark Python via a Jupyter Notebook - but in this case, you would need to set up your environment yourself. You can follow the guide on how to do this in this example Snowflake Lab: https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/snowpark-python-demos/tree/main/Advertising-Spend-ROI-Prediction